# Using qcodo with PHP7+

Tags: php, orm, qcodo, qcubed

I was just asked to check into what's involved in getting a qcodo-based application (http://www.qcodo.com) updated to work with PHP7+. I've seen others lauding qcubed (http://qcubed.github.io) which seems to be a crowd-sourced fork of qcodo but, as far as I can tell, there are no migration guides available on either official site.

Any insights on this task? Furthermore, anybody ever done a rewrite of qcodo to work with newer versions of PHP? What do you suggest as the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Qcubed should support PHP7+ in the newer versions. 
Your best bet is to port your existing solution to it and test to see what issues you run into.